# WP7 WebBrowser Control's NavigateToString is not displaying html data

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on the WebBrowser control in WP7 This is the sample HTML I wrote and asked the webBrowser to navigate To String than its working fine but when i stored this html in to variable and asked to navigate To String than out put is html format.My HTML string was came from web service so i am not able to pass direct string.

my C# code is:

```
            JObject cityblog1 = (JObject)cityblog[0];
            string cityimg = (string)cityblog1["CityImage"];
            string citydetail = (string)cityblog1["CityDetail"];

            City_Blog cb = new City_Blog();
            cb.CityImage = cityimg;
            cb.CityDetail = citydetail;
            lstcityblogdetail.Add(cb);
            setimg();

            //"\u003cbody style=\"text-align:justify\"\u003e\u003cp\u003e\r\n\tname\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\u003cp\u003e\r\n\t\u003ca href=\"36\" style=\"color: red\"\u003emovieplex\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\u003cp\u003e\r\n\t\u003ca href=\"47\" style=\"color: red\"\u003etest\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\u003c/body\u003e"
            webBrowser1.NavigateToString(citydetail);
```

see this string is came from web service when i pass this String than its give right output but when i strored this string in to citydetail variable and pass than it give output on html formate.

How can i solve this problem give some instruction.

Comment: are you sure that citydetail is not null?

try `citydetail = cityblog1["CityDetail"].ToString()` and check string for null or empty.

Comment: @ Milan Aggarwal:yes i am sure citydetail is not null.And citydetail = cityblog1["CityDetail"].ToString() it display the string on web browser controll

Comment: @MilanAggarwal:citydetail string=<body style="text-align:justify"><p>
 &amp;nbsp;</p>
<p>
 <a href="44" style="color: red">my web site</a></p>
<p>
 T&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; est</a></p>
<p>
 &amp;#39;</p>
</body>

Comment: @MilanAggarwal:so how can remove this &nbsp in my string please help me

Answer (score 0):

To remove `nbsp;` use this `citydetail.Replace("nbsp;","");`. You can also learn about using `Regex Expressions` according to your application.